# Woocommerce change checkout heading format

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've changed my 'Ship to a different address' box, using the following code -

```
// change text string
// 
function ra_change_translate_text_multiple( $translated ) {
$text = array(
    'RELATED PRODUCTS' => 'YOU MAY ALSO LIKE...',
    'SHIP TO A DIFFERENT ADDRESS?' => 'BUYING FOR SOMEONE ELSE',
    'Old Text 3' => 'New Translation 3',
);
$translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'ra_change_translate_text_multiple', 20 );
```

However, now i'd like to do two things -

1. change the font of the heading so it's the same as 'Billing Details' as per the attached pic.
2. Add a line of text under 'Billing Details' and 'Ship to a different address'

Can anyone assist with this please?

[image: headings example]

Comment: Problem 1 can be solved by using CSS to customize its look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is on the styling? do you have any css file that you can edit? add a style to both target the both heading and change them according to your need.

Comment: Thanks, I can add the CSS into the custom.css page, but I don't know what to add, to overright the current styling to it?

Comment: can I ask the exact screenshot of the inspector? I'll try to design it according to your screenshot.. thanks

Comment: try adding these code to the bottom of your custom.css

.woocommerce-billing-fields h3{ font-family: _italic_ font you are currently using; text-decoration: underline; }

Comment: Ahh okay.. that changes the "Billing Details" header... is there any way to change the "Ship to a different address header" rather please? I want to make it look like the "Billing Details" header. What reference do I use to do this? Thanks!! The url is https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/checkout/

Comment: use .woocommerce-shipping-fields #ship-to-different-address label span{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal;
}

Comment: ohhh thank you!! Thanks Brilliant!! You wouldn't know how to add the line of text underneath both headings would you please?!

Comment: for the underline of billing .woocommerce-billing-fields h3{ text-decoration: underline } and for the shipping .woocommerce-shipping-fields #ship-to-different-address label span{ text-decoration: underline }

Comment: No sorry, not underlining... I mean actually adding a small line of text underneath the 'Ship to a different address' line.

Comment: do you use a theme or child-theme? if so you can navigate to the theme's files and find woocoommerce folder.. find this path your /wp-content/themes/theme_name/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php and edit the file.. and add the line of text below the h3 tag

Comment: okay.. I can do that.. I use a child theme.. so if I make a copy of it, where do i put it? Does the copy only contain the changes? Sorry i'm not too familiar to with creating new documents in this area...

Comment: you don't actually need to copy the file if it already exists in your theme. Try navigating to wordpress backend and go to Appearance=>Editor, and find the file named form-billing.php and add the code or paragraph you want to insert

Comment: if you have skype u can add me and I'll try to share screen to you and show you how to add it.. I do have existing project that I'm doing the same as yours. my skype is https://join.skype.com/invite/HlJXC2GYmq5Y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181742/discussion-between-michelle-and-jeric-john-carillo).